# Where does WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings write its data? Not to web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, appsettings

I am trying to use WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[string] to read/write values to be stored in a configuration file on the server.  I thought that it read/wrote it to the Web.config file, or maybe app.config.  However, I ran the following test code - which the first time through (as desired) it throws an exception and but writes 'NOTSet' to that configuration entry - this allows me go easily go edit the file and change it to the correct value.

After running it a 2nd time, I can see the value returned is "NOTSet" - exactly as I would like.  The code is working exactly as planned.

Except - Where is it written?  I did a 'baregrep NOTSet *.*' - which recursively searched the ENTIRE project source directory and ONLY found the line in code that set the var - which means it was not written to anything in the entire project tree - not web.config, app.config or any other file.

I sighed, and said it must be in the registry - I searched the whole registry for anything with that value, then tried the key value - nothing.

Yet, running the program IS pulling the value that was set on the last run!  Where did my data go? I want to be able to edit the value- and more importantly, have a FILE that I can copy to the production web server with all the GUIDs set correctly.

```
public enum Guids
{
    IncidentSourceEnumPortal,
    WorkItemClass,
    WorkItemManagementPack
}

public class GuidConsts
{
  static readonly Dictionary<Guids, Guid>  GuidList = new Dictionary<Guids, Guid>();

    public static Guid Guids(Guids guidId)
    {
        if (!GuidList.ContainsKey(guidId))
        {
            string id = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[guidId.ToString()];

            Guid newGuid;

            if ( (id == null) || Guid.TryParse(id, out newGuid))
            {
                WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[guidId.ToString()] = "NOTSet";
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Invalid guid - not found in Config: {0}", guidId));
            }
            GuidList.Add(guidId, newGuid);
            return newGuid;
        }

        return GuidList[guidId];
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG It appears the answer is 'in memory' - it isn't flushing it to the disk anywhere, and if I close Visual Studio and reopen it then the value is gone.  So, is there a way to get it to flush to the disk?  Or a better way to do this?  (A file called 'guids.config' next to the web.config seems like a good idea.)

Comment: I tried switching to the joke? class WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration ("ignored-path")   Which seems to only "open" the file if it exists, but then it creates 22 seconds, 10 section groups, no file path, no file assoc. and I only have 6 XML element tags - so wtf does it get the 22 tags from, why can't I save it, WHY IS THIS HARD?  I'm doing this from a webpage - using 'ConfigurationFileMap and OpenMappedMachineConfiguration is equally useless

Answer (score 0):

To save the web.config file you need to call `Configuration.Save()` to persist changes. They are not automatically saved when you change a value:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Writing to web.config on the fly is not really advisable anyway, for one thing it will cause the app pool to be restarted potentially resulting in loss of session state across your application and probably other application-wide things you don't want to happen.

Comment: Well, it should only ever happen in development - as this is a hard coded enum value.  I did it to make the creation of new GUIDs easier.

Comment: config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/guids.config"); - Doesn't work because it doesn't really open the file, but requires it to exist, then cashes the contents in RAM and throws an exception on Save().

Comment: Well, it appears if you call '.AppSettings' - Even on a config object that points to a TOTALLY DIFFERENT file (per above) it will PULL FROM WEB.CONFIG - WTF?? Seriously?  Can someone who knows how to use this help, as this is just wrong, wrong wrong as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TraderhutGames config files stack, so your web.config will consist of stuff inherited from various files in the heirarchy such as machine.config https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.140%29.aspx. What is the exception you are getting when you try and save?

Comment: I am not getting any exception when I "save" - however, no files are updated when I "save" - it appears to be storing it in memory somewhere as it continues to have that value until I exit visual studio and restart it - then it loses the value.

Comment: In reference to the stacking, when I open a specific file it stacks - so I can't not define something in my file and open it and have it not defined - unless every other file that is stacked with it also has it undefined.  Is there any interface to doing something simple like getting appsettings from a single file - with an easy string interface?   Kind of makes me long for .Ini files again.

Comment: I also don't buy that they stack - I can have it working correctly using:             config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/guids.config"); - with my settings in the web.config file - NOT in the guids.config, and it pulls them in - OK, it is stacking.  I copy the entire contents of web.config to guids.config, and then remove those values from the web.config and I get NULL back for all the values - not stacking, just ignoring the filename that is passed (I get an exception if it doesn't exist, but it doesn't read it if it does???)

Comment: This is driving me nuts too. Did you find a solution? My code works as expected, i.e. config settings are saved. But I can't figure out where.

Comment: Have a look in your bin/Release or bin/Debug folder